# Writing to XML file via AJAX and ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, xml, ajax, webforms

I am trying to use $.ajax.post using:

```
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/products/SaveXML.aspx",
                data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
            });               
        });
```

SaveXML lookes like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script language="c#" runat="server">

public void testMethod()
{              
    string sayHello = "hello world";
}

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Eventually, I want to pass in some XML and have SaveXML handle it.

Does the code need to be in a code-behind?  Does it need to be marked as a web method?

Can someone show me what this should look like please?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use GenericHttpHandler and implement processrequest method. In your process request method do xml writing logic based on the data you received in HttpContext parameter and send some Response code or key to identify the success in ajax.

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs indeed to be server side code (which doesn't mean you have to have a code behind file - what you have with your `testMethod` will work just fine, as it is in a server side context).

Since you are *posting* the data to the `.aspx` page, there is no need to use a web method. You can use `Page_Load` or `OnInit` to get the posted data (via the `Request` page property) and handle the posted data in it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into both answers.

Comment: So, to get simple feedback from the 'success' function, what I have should work or do I need to implement a page_Load too?

Comment: @davy - You don't have to, but you do need to _output_ something on the page. That "something" is your response value, and the HTTP success header (should be 200 if all is well) will indicate success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Page Methods with jQuery.

Check this:

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at this but still no joy so far.